# Cannot Scroll Left or right side of UIImageView in UIScrollView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view inside a scrollview which contains imageview. Using the `viewForZooming` trying to zoom in and zoom out functionality for the image view. I can zoom in and zoom out the image. However, I have trouble in scrolling left side or right side of the image after zooming in.

My Main (Base) looks like,

[! [Main Base Hierarchy here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCoPF.png)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCoPF.png)

My Code,

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

In ViewDidLoad(),

```
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
scrollView.contentSize = Img.frame.size
scrollView.delegate = self
```

My extension code,

```
extension CardsViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
   let trailingSpace: CGFloat = 10
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
      let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
      let x = screenSize.width - self.cardbgView.frame.size.width - trailingSpace
      let y = self.cardbgView.frame.origin.y
      self.cardbgView.frame = 
      CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: self.cardbgView.frame.size.width, height:self.cardbgView.frame.size.height)
  })
   return cardbgView
}
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to zoom in the image and scroll left side and right side as well as move the zoomed image all sides to view/read the image

Comment: Remove everything from `viewForZoomin` except for the `return cardbgView` line.

Comment: @HangarRash I gave a try on that and the issue remains still. Thanks!!!